# Ubuntu 20.04 VPS not showing the actual disk size

Tags: server, upgrade, disk, vps, nvme

I just bought a VPS Linux Ubuntu 20.04 which uses NVMe and storage which is said to be 80GB, I tried running `apt update && apt full-upgrade -y` and everything works normally, I intend to upgrade my Ubuntu to 22.04 with the command `do-release-upgrade` but the command finishes with an error saying:

```
Not enough free disk space

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 1,713 M free
space on disk '/'. Please free at least an additional 119 M of disk
space on '/'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of
former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

I'm confused, because I just bought this VPS a few minutes ago, I haven't even installed anything yet, I tried running the command `df -H --total` and this is the result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev
tmpfs           834M  599k  833M   1% /run
/dev/vda1       4.8G  2.9G  1.6G  65% /
tmpfs           4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           834M     0  834M   0% /run/user/0
total            19G  2.9G   16G  16% -
```

The results make me even more confused, why is the disk size not 80GB as it should be?

BUT.....
`$ lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
vda    252:0    0   80G  0 disk
├─vda1 252:1    0   78G  0 part /
└─vda2 252:2    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
```

**HELLPPP MEEEE**

Comment: @Thomas Ward Gosh, thank you so much bro, it worked, I looked everywhere for a fix, and it turns out I just had to run this command, damn it

Comment: "Expand ext filesystem" is what you would look for but I'll move my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is because your *filesystem* has a smaller size than the actual *partition* it's on.  This *can* happen, but usually happens that it starts smaller, and you've expanded the disk size, but then didn't go back and expand the *filesystem* to fit.

That's actually really easy to fix, since we know the device is `/dev/vda1` from your output, we just tell the system to expand the filesystem to fill available space:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/vda1
```

This will automatically expand the filesystem to fill the 78GB of available partition space.